# Error while using template for vm domain join

Tags: active-directory, azure, virtual-machines

I'm trying to use below template to add VM to domain in Azure.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/201-vm-domain-join-existing/azuredeploy.json (template: vm_domain_join.json below)

I am providing vmName and locationName as variable but getting below errors while executing - az group deployment create:

`resourceGroupName="xxxx"
locationName="xxxx"
vmName="xxxx"`

`az group deployment create --resource-group "$resourceGroupName" --template-file vm_domain_join.json --parameters '{ "vmList": {"value":"$vmName"}, "location": {"value":"$locationName"}, "domainJoinUserName": {"value":"xxxxx"}, "domainJoinUserPassword":{"value":"xxxxx"}, "domainFQDN":{"value":"xxxxx"}, "ouPath":{"value":"xxxxx"} }'`

Location variable error:

`Azure Error: InvalidResourceLocation
Message: The specified location '$locationName' is invalid. A location must consist of characters, whitespace, digit, or following symbols '(,)'.`

VM variable error:

`"error": {
    "code": "ParentResourceNotFound",
    "message": "Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource '$vmName' not found."
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters variables are all inside a single quote block, so they are take literally and not expanded , change them to double quotes and escape the inside quotes, like:

```
"{ \"vmList\": {\"value\":\"$vmName\"}, \"location\": {\"value\":\"$locationName\"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameter can be provided to template file using following method:

Example:
az group deployment create --resource-group $rgname --template-file configfile.json --parameters vmList=$vmmachinename location=$location